# collation conflict between "Hebrew_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation, collate

in some procedure that i work on, i write this code:

```
update a
set a.custName = b.custName
from #x as a inner join pl_Customer as b on a.Company_Code = b.Company_Code and a.cust = b.Cust
```

ans i got this error:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Hebrew_CI_AS" and
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

i try so solve it with this:

```
update a
set a.custName = b.custName
from #x as a inner join pl_Customer as b on a.Company_Code = b.Company_Code and a.cust = b.Cust
collate Latin1_General_CI_AI;
```

but it is still error.

Comment: Seems like your table definitions are inconsistent. Fix that, and the problem is gone.

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: Why did you create a temp table with a different collation?

Comment: Both cust columns should have the same collation.

Comment: where should i change it?

Comment: @M.R. .  I think you need to change the collation to `set`.

Comment: `a.cust collate database_default = b.cust collate database_default` in join condition

Comment: @ValiMaties that would be a bad idea - the server can't use indexes in that case and has to perform a full scan. Besides, it's a temporary table. Either an application or a stored procedure had to create it. It's far easier to just avoid the problem by fixing that script than trying to recover from it afterwards

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , the example I learned from mssqltips.com... 
here  is the link: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4395/understanding-the-collate-databasedefault-clause-in-sql-server/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Temporary tables are created using the server's collation by default. It looks like your server's collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` and the database's (actually, the column's) `Hebrew_CI_AS` or vice versa.

You can overcome this by using `collate database_default` in the temporary table's column definitions, eg :

```
create #x (
    ID int PRIMARY KEY,
    Company_Code nvarchar(20) COLLATE database_default,
    Cust nvarchar(20) COLLATE database_default,
    ...
)
```

This will create the columns using the current database's collation, not the server's.

Comment: Or he can put `collate database_default` in join condition, like `a.cust collate database_default = b.cust collate database_default` , and it will collate both columns as database default collation, as columns may have different collation than database.

Comment: @ValiMaties that would be a bad idea - the server can't use indexes in that case and has to perform a full scan. Besides, it's a *temporary* table. Either an application or a stored procedure had to create it. It's far easier to just avoid the problem by fixing that script than trying to recover from it afterwards

Answer (score 3):

In your temp table definition #x,add COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT  to the String columns, like

```
custName nvarchar(xx) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL
```